# ASP.NET MVC 5 thread safe cache?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, caching

Help guys, have products list with singleton class with caching and these 2 methods:

```
private readonly static object Lock = new object();

private List<BaseItem> GetProducts()
{
    lock (Lock)
    {
        List<BaseItem> products = (List<BaseItem>)HttpRuntime.Cache.Get("Products");

        if (products == null)
        {
            products = DBManager.inst.GetProducts();
            HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert("Products", products, null,
            DateTime.MaxValue, TimeSpan.FromHours(48));
        }

        return products;
    }
}
```

And `GetProduct`:

```
public BaseItem GetProduct(int ArticulID)
{
    lock (Lock)
    {
        return GetProducts().Where(x => x.Articul == ArticulID).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Is this the right solution - is it thread safe?

Answer (score 0):

I would use `MemoryCache`. It is thread safe and you don't need the `lock` anymore. Install it using the [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.Caching). More sense would make to add each `BaseItem` individually into the cache with a unique key, but this is up to you.

```
    MemoryCache memChInst = new MemoryCache("Products");

    List<BaseItem> testList = new List<BaseItem>() { new BaseItem() { Id = 1 }, new BaseItem { Id = 3 } };

    List<BaseItem> GetProducts()
    {          
        var  retData =  (List<BaseItem >)memChInst.AddOrGetExisting("Key1", testList, new CacheItemPolicy { AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddHours(48) });
        return retData ?? testList;
    }

    var xx =GetProducts();
    var yy = GetProducts();
    var zz = GetProducts();
```